# Can't make sense of this exception in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on an Android Kotlin program and I am trying to compare a byte (from a bytearray) to a constant I have:

```
if (myBytes[0] == myConstants.CheckByte)
```

But I am getting this exception:
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError : Field is not static: MemberDescription(ownerInternalName = myConstants, name = CheckByte, desc = B, isStatic = true)

But it is not making sense to me, it says *isStatic = true* so why the exception?

myConstants is setup like this:

```
object myConstants {
   val CheckByte: Byte = 0x13
}
```

Comment: This example seems to compile just fine, there must be something you're not including - https://pl.kotl.in/h4HuZgHmf